# Simple translation from Python to R

Tags: python, r

I am trying to learn R but just can't quite grasp the syntax. Python is just so much more intuitive for me. I am playing with the `nycflights13` toy dataset in R, and what to figure out how to do this simple execution

```
test = df.groupby('tailnum').agg({'flight':'count','arr_delay':'sum'})
test[(test.flight>=12)].sort_values(by='arr_delay',ascending=False)
```

and get

```
      flight arr_delay
tailnum     
N15910  280 7317.0
N15980  316 7134.0
N16919  251 6904.0
N228JB  388 6778.0
N14998  230 6087.0
... ... ...
N711ZX  291 -2154.0
N722TW  314 -2199.0
N721TW  318 -2285.0
N718TW  328 -2335.0
N727TW  275 -2642.0
```

I tried the following, but the numbers are off. I'm missing something.

```
test <- flights %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
    filter(n()>=12) %>%
  summarize(total_delay = sum(arr_delay))

test[order(test$total_delay,decreasing = FALSE),]
```

and got

```
tailnum total_delay
<chr>   <dbl>
N961UW  -1197           
N37700  -1148           
N3754A  -1084           
N847VA  -1006   
...
N179JB  4449
```

In short, python user is a complete noob with R and trying to get better, plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R doesn't drop `NA` values by default while taking `sum` or `mean`, add `na.rm. =TRUE` and use `arrange` to order the data.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(flight = n(), 
            arr_delay = sum(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))   %>%
  filter(flight >= 12) %>%
  arrange(desc(arr_delay))

#  tailnum flight arr_delay
#   <chr>    <int>     <dbl>
# 1 N15910     280      7317
# 2 N15980     316      7134
# 3 N16919     251      6904
# 4 N228JB     388      6778
# 5 N14998     230      6087
# 6 N192JB     319      5810
# 7 N292JB     322      5804
# 8 N12921     280      5788
# 9 N13958     259      5620
#10 N10575     289      5566
# … with 3,369 more rows
```